# Property function counting prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\Pi$ be the usual function counting prime numbers. Show that for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, exists $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$\Pi((k+1)^2)-\Pi(k^2) \geq n$$

I tried to use the Prime Numbers Theorem to estimate how many prime numbers should exist between $(k+1)^2$ and $k^2$ in the form
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{p_n}{n\log n} =1 $$ 
But that was not good to estimate the difference of the function between consecutive squares

Comment: And what question are you asking?

Comment: See also [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_conjecture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each prime less than $x$ is put into a group according to which squares it is surrounded by, there are $\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$ groups.  Therefore at least one of those groups has more than $\frac{\pi(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ primes, and by the prime number theorem this value tends to infinity.

Comment: Simple and elegant argument. Nice. Thanks